# Endless loop in onSensorChanged

Tags: android, infinite-loop

Help! I've fallen into an endless loop and I can't get up!

RESULTS

**** MisbehavingActivity onCreate.

**** MisbehavingActivity onResume Register.

**** MisbehavingActivity onAccuracyChanged.

**** MisbehavingActivity Accelerometer onSensorChanged.

**** MisbehavingActivity onPause Unregister.

**** MisbehavingActivity Accelerometer onSensorChanged.

**** MisbehavingActivity onPause Unregister.

**** MisbehavingActivity Accelerometer onSensorChanged.

**** MisbehavingActivity onPause Unregister.

**** MisbehavingActivity Accelerometer onSensorChanged.

**** MisbehavingActivity onPause Unregister.

**** MisbehavingActivity Accelerometer onSensorChanged.

**** MisbehavingActivity onPause Unregister.

etc. etc. until:

"**Unfortunately, Amiok has stopped**"

Here's the code:

```
package com.apackage.amiok;

import android.content.Context;
//import android.content.Intent;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import static android.hardware.Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MisbehavingActivity extends AbstrActivity  implements OnClickListener, SensorEventListener {

    private static final String TOAST = "**** MisbehavingActivity ";
    SensorManager sensorManager;
    Sensor accelerometer;
    Button aButton;
    //SensorEventListener sensorListener;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        logStuff( TOAST + "onCreate. ");

        sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        accelerometer = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 

        aButton = ((Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonToStop));
        aButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        logStuff( TOAST + "onClick.");
        onPause();
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        logStuff( TOAST + "onResume Register.");
        super.onResume();
        // register the listener
        accelerometer = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        sensorManager.registerListener(this, accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        logStuff( TOAST + "onPause Unregister.");

        // unregister the listener for all sensors
        sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
        super.onPause();
    }


    // SensorEventListener stuff

        @Override
        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) { 
            logStuff( TOAST + "Accelerometer onSensorChanged.");  
            onPause();
            finish();

        }

        @Override
        public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
            logStuff( TOAST + "onAccuracyChanged.");
            // Not sure I need to do anything here...
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are registering the Activity instance as SensorEventListener twice, on onCreate and onResume method, leave only one registration, on onResume method and delete registration on onCreate method. As good practice call first super methods onPause and onResume. Look a example code on [SensorManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html).

Comment: Thanks, Joseph!  I actually had it that way in the first place, but I got the exact same results, so I changed it.  The real question is why isn't my "unregisterListener" statement working?

Comment: Hmm. I made those "good practice" changes you suggested, Joseph, and also replaced all the calls to logStuff (which is in my AbstrActivity) with makeNotification, and that helped somewhat, but it still seems like the onSensorChanged method is getting called at least twice before I can unregister!  At least it's not crashing now. Thanks!